# Dimensional Tolerances Using Fractions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an engineering/architectural drawing. 
It says dimension A should be 1" ± 1/16". 
I have entered those values into an Excel worksheet. 
How do I write a formula that will take that information
and compare it to my input and give me a pass/fail?

For example,

| NOMINAL DIMENSION | ACTUAL DIMENSION | ± | TOL |  | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 1/32 | ± | 1/16 | … | Pass |
| 1 | 1 1/8 | ± | 1/16 | … | Fail |

[image: [Another example (as an image)]]

Comment: which 1 is input.. ?  |  "give me a pass/fail?" <-- is this the output.?

Comment: Where do you want the output(is that your Acc/Rej/Need App columns)? Or are you looking for a conditional formatting highlighting cells green/red/yellow (stoplight) format? As for a formula what have you tried? Edit your questions with these, and more people may be willing to help you. As for your main question, I would probably use the absolute value formula and compare that result with the tolerance.

Comment: (1) Are the numbers stored as numbers or as strings?  (2) How do you know the desired results? You can do the computation by hand, right? If you understand the process, try to express it as a formula.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your data table's image, let's say the columns are A through I. In that case, we need columns C, B, and E.

Use the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(VALUE(LEFT(C7,LEN(C7)-1))>=VALUE(LEFT(B7,LEN(B7)-1))-VALUE(LEFT(E7,LEN(E7)-1)),VALUE(LEFT(C7,LEN(C7)-1))<=VALUE(LEFT(B7,LEN(B7)-1))+VALUE(LEFT(E7,LEN(E7)-1))),"Pass","Fail")
```

which is the following except it deals with the inch indicators (the " after each value) being present. UGLY, but it works. More on that at the END. (The following just shows the logic. It would fails because it doesn't remove those " indicators.)

```
=IF(AND(C7>=B7-E7,  C7<=B7+E7),"Pass","Fail")
```

Copy and paste down to match your data rows.

You do not indicate an Excel version so perhaps you have the most recent and can use  `LET()` to clear that up some:

```
=LET(Nominal,  VALUE(LEFT(B7,LEN(B7)-1)),
     Tolerance,  VALUE(LEFT(E7,LEN(E7)-1)),
     Actual,  VALUE(LEFT(C7,LEN(C7)-1)),
     
     IF(AND(Actual>=Nominal-Tolerance,Actual<=Nominal+Tolerance),"Pass","Fail")
    )
```

It uses `AND()` to take the Nominal Dimension and subtracts the tolerance, then compare it to your Actual Dimension looking to see if the Actual Dimension is equal to that lower limit, or higher. Then it does the opposite idea, checking to see if it is less than or equal to the Nominal Dimension PLUS the tolerance. If it meets BOTH conditions, then it has to be equal to either end or in between them. Therefore it passes, which the formula indicates. If it fails either test in the `AND()`, it give the FALSE result:  "Fail" (as is desired).

It would be trickier if you had tolerances like "+1/16, -1/64" but not by much:  you'd just use `MID()` to pull them out of the string in the cell and use each part appropriately in the formula.

To use the hugely clearer formula I put in for showing the logic, you can consider a change to your data. I'll admit, you may already be doing this, but one guesses you are not. That is that you can format your number values to add literal characters in them, at their beginnings, or at their ends. So you could use this number format: `### #0/##\"` and enter the values in these cells as simply numbers letting Excel add the `"` at their ends. That would keep them always numbers, never strings. A formula can then use the number value directly instead of having to remove that `"` from the end because any call on their values only sees the number, not the extra bit at the end of the displayed version. Considering this idea could be useful in many, many other places.

**Always** up to you (or... your boss) how you choose to go with things like that.

By the way, if you have a ton of entries with the `"` indicators, you can remove them by highlighting the cells and using `Find and Replace` to lose them. THEN do the formatting, not before. So changing would be easy. Changing multiple people's entry practices, much harder... but changing the spreadsheet would be easy.

That trick also works other ways. You can format a cell as, say, `#,##0 "horses and light years"` and a value of `38` would display as `38 horses and light years` but the `38` would be the only thing "really" there if another cell used it for something.